# fb-video change url and reload player at runtime (without page refresh)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

How do I change the video URL of fb-video at runtime and make the player reload the video without page refresh:

```
    <div id="fb-root" style="height: auto"></div>
    <script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div class="fb-video"
         data-href="https://www.facebook.com/abcxyz/videos/vb.123/123/?type=1"
         data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
```

That is the code I have now in the HTML that works as the page is loaded. I just want to know now if its possible to somehow change the data-href then make the Facebook embedded video player point to a new video.

Comment: I placed it in a modal

Comment: That is not a helpful answer. Please be concrete about it: Edit your question and add a complete, coherent, minimal code snippet that demonstrates what *exactly*you have tried.

Comment: @derabbink well I fixed this issue already with that simple answer :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the JavaScript SDK's `FB.XFBML.parse()` method after changing the `data-href` attribute's value.

Here's some documentation:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

I tried to create a CodePen or JSBin example, but Facebook's SDK script doesn't play nicely with sandboxed iframes (it tries to change `document.domain`, which isn't allowed), so nothing would load. This approach does work for me in a current project, though.

Answer (score -1):

```json
{
  "session_key": "5.zj24rk1iHCRNQw.1602142801.26-100055829688425",
  "uid": 100055829688425,
  "secret": "9d6082e678f882fa59131bb90425ed03",
  "access_token": "EAAAAAYsX7TsBACy8MNjCjeFlxoLUfHAetnLNUEFCHjiRdyJoL6Td9LaM6J7sUfvCWDrugNUKt68DQ0kZAzSHoXDA0ZCZB1ePVZBAWNY7r7HQe5ZApXWCxqPpuJ9fgUgnHjcZCTUVhkBBdExuYsDQI7DWXJGfgsIE2JDPYZCDdZBCjR1Cn6Sg5bd1IkHlZBwDey5LEGO50weSYD9yp9XI7xEuKVIGjAXhDlAsZD",
  "machine_id": "UcJ-X0qUMXyP0GIAuWWn4oML",
  "session_cookies": [
    {
      "name": "c_user",
      "value": "100055829688425",
      "expires": "Fri, 08 Oct 2021 07:40:01 GMT",
      "expires_timestamp": 1633678801,
      "domain": ".facebook.com",
      "path": "/",
      "secure": true
    },
    {
      "name": "xs",
      "value": "26:zj24rk1iHCRNQw:2:1602142801:-1:-1",
      "expires": "Fri, 08 Oct 2021 07:40:01 GMT",
      "expires_timestamp": 1633678801,
      "domain": ".facebook.com",
      "path": "/",
      "secure": true,
      "httponly": true
    },
    {
      "name": "fr",
      "value": "1f1Zr9NS95lcQZvgt.AWXy6-fEd6goo-3y9NGBO-FG6FU.BfeVtZ.NH.AAA.0.0.BffsJR.AWXNkwt0ybw",
      "expires": "Wed, 06 Jan 2021 07:39:59 GMT",
      "expires_timestamp": 1609918799,
      "domain": ".facebook.com",
      "path": "/",
      "secure": true,
      "httponly": true
    },
    {
      "name": "datr",
      "value": "UcJ-X0qUMXyP0GIAuWWn4oML",
      "expires": "Sat, 08 Oct 2022 07:40:01 GMT",
      "expires_timestamp": 1665214801,
      "domain": ".facebook.com",
      "path": "/",
      "secure": true,
      "httponly": true
    }
  ],
  "confirmed": true,
  "identifier": "7736786462"
}
```