# FB.XFBML.parse reloads the whole page instead of reloading the content for fb-videos

Tags: javascript, facebook

I loaded two videos statically and the third one dynamically using     `

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("container-id"));
```

But instead of reloading the contaier it reloads the whole page.

```
<body>
    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
    </script>
    <!-- Your embedded video player code -->
    <div id="video-basket">
        <div  
            class="fb-video"
            data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook/videos/10153231379946729/" 
            data-width="500" 
            data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
        <div  
            class="fb-video"
            data-href="https://www.facebook.com/MichaelMcIntyreFans/videos/1418120488209365/" 
            data-width="500"
            data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="cutty-video-basket"></div>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            facebook = "";
            /* Facebook videos initialization */
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({
                    appId: '{1367462833276100}',
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: 'v2.8'
                });
                facebook = FB;
            };
            (function (d, s, id) {
                var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                if (d.getElementById(id)) {
                    return;
                }
                js = d.createElement(s);
                js.id = id;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
            /* Facebook videos initialization */

            /* Load the third video dynamically after five seconds */
            setTimeout(function () {
                var str = '<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/thehumaneleague/videos/1740263742655957/" data-width="500" data-allowfullscreen="true"></div>';
                $("#cutty-video-basket").append(str);
                facebook.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("comment_basket"));
            }, 5000);
            /* Load the third video dynamically after five seconds */
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

But this same code for fb-comments works fine and it didn't reloads the page only the container. Please note that I have read [some questions but](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564069/fb-video-change-url-and-reload-player-at-runtime-without-page-refresh) what I need is to load fb-video **on a new div dynamically** **Not by modifying the data-href of an existing one**.

Answer (score 0):

My Bad, it should be

```
   facebook.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("cutty-video-basket"));
```

not

```
facebook.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById("comment_basket"));
```

Notable thing is as per my expectation, it loads dynamically without reloading.